# IE doesn't display blinking cursor on pre-filled input fields

Tags: internet-explorer, cursor, textfield

In all versions of IE, I've noticed that if I have an input field with a preset value, the blinking cursor will not display when I hit tab to focus the field (though the field does focus and I can begin typing). It only appears once I begin typing, or, alternatively, if I click into the field with the mouse instead of using the tab key.

It seems like a legit bug since IE is the only browser that does it, and it happens even if there's no styling applied to the fields.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

The previous didn't work in my case but the .select() did the trick:

```
$('input').focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == preFilledText) $(this).val('').select();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could 'fake' typing into the field with something like this in jQuery. Not sure if it works, just a suggestion I freeformed right now. This clears the input box then refills it on focus time.

```
var loInput = $("#MyInputBox");
loInput.focus(function() {
    var lcVal = loInput.val();
    loInput.val('');
    loInput.val(lcVal);
});
```